# GCS: change object-level permission control to bucket-level

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I created a GCS bucket and made it public by granting READER to allUsers, so I expect all objects in the bucket will be publicly accessible, but turns out only the bucket is readable, objects are not.

I guess it is because I enabled object-level permission control for the bucket, my questions: 1) how can I verify whether it is object-level permission control or not? 2) how can I update it to bucket-level permission control?

I need gsutil based solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Bucket Policy Only documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-policy-only

1 - you're looking for `gsutil bucketonlypolicy get`

```
$ gsutil bucketpolicyonly get gs://my-test-bucket
Bucket Policy Only setting for gs://my-test-bucket:
Enabled: True
LockedTime: 2019-07-09 16:14:31.777000+00:00
```

2 - check `gsutil bucketonlypolicy set`

```
$ gsutil bucketpolicyonly set on gs://my-test-default-acl-bucket/
Enabling Bucket Policy Only for gs://my-test-default-acl-bucket...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Also I need to set IAM instead ACL to make it public https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets